# writing a query that contains two constraints on the same table

Tags: sql

I am aware that I am asking something that may look trivial but I could not find and answer or a duplicate. (I am new with this area).
So i am trying.

I have two tables
Tests table with the following columns

```
1. storyID , authorID , assigneeID
2. userID , userName
```

I would like to write a query that return `storyID, UserName of author ID, UserName of assigneeID`.

Comment: does userID = authorID and(or) assigneID

Comment: Yes. Indeed they are

Comment: The lesson to learn from this: Use names that relate to the parent column. E.g. `author_userid`, `assignee_userid` would make clear we are talking about user IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT storyID, u1.userName AS authorName, u2.userName AS assigneeName 
FROM storytable s 
INNER JOIN usertable u1 ON s.authorID = u1.userID 
INNER JOIN usertable u2 ON s.assigneeID = u2.userID
```

The above solution will only work in case you have relation between userID, assigneeID and authorID fields.

Answer (score 0):

Select and create an alias for the second table.

```
SELECT a.storyID, b.userName, c.userName
FROM tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.authorID = b.userID
INNER JOIN tableb c ON a.assigneeID= c.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the authorID = UserId...

```
select 
     1.storyId, 
     author.userName,
     assignee.userName 
 from 1
 inner join 2 as author 
      on 1.authorId = 2.userId 
 inner join 2 as assignee
      on 1.assigneeID = 2.userID
```